# Index.php as custom error page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-status-codes, errordocument

I'm using Apache 2.2.X and PHP 5.2.X (installed as Apache module) to build a new website and I would like to read your suggestions about how I'm trying to handle server errors.
I was thinking about using the same file of my homepage (/index.php) to show custom error messages.
This is my .htaccess setup:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /index.php?error=400
ErrorDocument 401 /index.php?error=401
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php?error=403
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?error=404
ErrorDocument 500 /index.php?error=500
```

Now, in my index.php file I have some code that looks like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['error']))
    DrawErrorPage($_GET['error']);
else
    DrawHomepage();
```

Everything works like a charm.
Well, everything except one thing that I can't fix: if I force Apache to respond with a 500 status code (for example, inserting malformed code into my .htaccess), I'm not being redirected to "/index.php?error=500", but I get the default 500 error page instead. With any other status code (for example, 403 or 404) my configuration works absolutely perfectly.
But now I've a doubt and I'm starting to think that it would be better to use another page to handle errors (for example, "/error.php").
"DrawHomepage()" needs to set "robots" meta tag to "index, follow", while "DrawErrorPage()" needs to set it to "noindex, nofollow". Right? So... what would happen if a web crawler gets an error response visiting my homepage for the first time? What would happen if a web crawler gets 200 visiting my homepage for the first time, but a 500 visiting it a month later? And what would happen if I keep my "robots" meta tag to "index, follow" even if I'm showing errors?
Is there a workaround, a solution, for this problem? What would you do?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually if there is a 500 status code then Apache has messed something up and *it can't run* your index.php file, resulting in *another* 500 status code. Apache continues this error loop for a few iterations before it finally says "no more loops" and sending its own error page.

The only really safe way to display a custom page for a 500 status code is to use plain text or use a basic .html or .shtml file that doesn't try to access other things on your server, so you don't keep triggering more 500 status codes in the page load.

Usually if a crawler encounters a 500, it will just ignore the page temporarily. A 500 code is recoverable, it doesn't necessarily mean there is no page there, just that the server is messed up at the moment. The bots are smart and can determine what error codes mean what, as long as the page is always *sending* the status code in the page header.

Remember, if you use a PHP file as your error document, you need to resend the HTTP status code using the header function inside PHP to ensure proper page detection, like so:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 404 Page Not Found");
```

Comment: So, for example, if I print a 403 error on my page, I also need to send 403 header right? For what concerns crawlers and temporary errors it's ok, I understand... but does it also work if user enters, for example, "/non-existant.gif" and gets redirected to "/index.php?error=400"? What would happen? Crawler hits index.php and receives a 404 status code... isn't that bad for indexing? And what kind of "robots" meta tag should I use in both cases?

Comment: When a user hits a file they don't have access too or doesn't exist, whatever the reason is, the page doesn't actually get redirected. The URL in the address bar stays the same and the *file that's executed* gets changed by Apache. This file can store data about the error, display a custom page, but it also needs to send an appropriate error code (such as a 404) so bots or whoever accessed it will stop trying to access it. You're not saying index.php doesn't exist, you're saying that path they accessed doesn't exist. I'm not sure what you mean by robots meta tag.

Comment: When I print my homepage (so I'm not on /index.php because an ErrorDocument directive called it), I would like the crawlers to navigate every link and index it, so I put "index, follow" on robots meta. But if I'm using /index.php to print a custom error, I would like to change that header to "noindex, nofollow" because I don't want an erro page to be indexed and followed by crawlers. Being always the same file... could this tag swap cause problems to my site indexing?

Comment: @Zarathos: If a crawler follows a link to a file that doesn't exist, it will just assume that it doesn't exist. If later the file does appear (exist), the crawler will eventually follow that link again and determine that the page exists now and index it. You seem to be confused how the index.php file is working though. The index.php is only the file being used to print the page and ***not*** the actual page the bot is looking at. As long as you send a HTTP status code when your index.php processes an error page, you should be fine.