# index.html as error page

Tags: php, apache, errordocument

I'm trying to use my index.html page as one of my ErrorDocument pages in Apache.

*VERY SIMILAR* to what this guy is doing here:
[Index.php as custom error page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498334/index-php-as-custom-error-page)

But without using PHP (server is running hot as it is).

**What I've tried so far**

Not much. Setting `ErrorDocument 401 index.html` puts Apache in an infinite deny loop.

Any way around this (again without PHP)?

**Edit:**

My .htaccess file at document root:

```
AuthUserFile /yep/this/path/exists/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Please Enter Password"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user

#ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
ErrorDocument 401 /index.html
#ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
#ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
#ErrorDocument 402 http://www.example.com/subscription_info.html
```

Comment: you may have to edit the .htacess file.

Comment: an "infinite deny loop"? It looks like you're doing it correctly. Check permissions on index.html. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html

Comment: @mankadanka yep, that is where I am doing the edit. Still no love.

Comment: If you provide the changes made, that would be helpful for the community to help you.

Comment: @cantelope no, permissions seem fine - commenting out the 401 line and entering the right credentials does produce the webpage as expected.

Comment: @mankadanka done - when I enter correct credentials, index.html loads correctly. Incorrectly, it enters a deny loop (breaks after 5 requests). This is expected. I just want to know if there's a way to produce a custom ErrorDocument based on my index.html without PHP (something like: index.html?code=401)

Comment: For me, it doesn't make sense to put `index` at an error page. Suppose that there is an error in index page, then it will redirect to the error page, in this case the page that previous had the error.

Comment: @Eduardo I agree, but I was looking for a cheap and dirty solution similar to what the guy in my first link did. Just without PHP.